# Prove that if $z_n \rightarrow z$ then $\theta_n \rightarrow \theta$ and $r_n \rightarrow r$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose that $z_n,z \in G = \mathbb{C} - \{z:z\leq 0\}$ and $z_n=r_ne^{i\theta_n}, z = re^{i\theta}$ where $- \pi < \theta_n,\theta< \pi$. Prove that if $z_n \rightarrow z$ then $\theta_n \rightarrow \theta$ and $r_n \rightarrow r$.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I tried to use the definition in the convergences of real and imaginary parts. But I think I may have to use some branch of the logarithm for defining the set G.

Comment: Independent of $\theta$, can you show that $r_n\to r$? (Hint: all points with modulus $r$ lie on the circle of radius $r$; what if $r_n\not\to r$?)

Comment: If $z$ is a complex number, how can you say $z \leq 0$?

Comment: Assuming you require $r = r(z)\geq 0$, then write $r(z)=|z|$. Can you show $r$ is continuous? If so, what can you conclude about the sequence $r(z_n)$ if you know that $z_n\rightarrow z$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $z_n\to z$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N_\varepsilon$ such that for any $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, $\|z-z_n\|\leq\varepsilon$.

Now we have:
$$\forall n\geq N_\varepsilon,\qquad \left|\|z\|-\|z_n\|\right|\leq \|z-z_n\|=\varepsilon, $$
hence $\|z_n\|=r_n\to r=\|z\|$.

Assuming that $\varepsilon\leq \frac{r}{2}\cdot\left|\sin\arg(z)\right|$ and that $\|z-z_n\|\leq\varepsilon$, we have:
$$\left|\arg z-\arg z_n\right|\leq \arcsin\frac{\varepsilon}{r},$$
hence $\theta_n\to\theta$.

Comment: Nice. Maybe also point out that $|z_{n}|=r_{n}$ for clarity.

Comment: The question is: where I use the definition of G?

Comment: It is used in a implicit way: $\arg z,\arg z_n$ are well-defined and belong to $(-\pi,\pi)$ since $z,z_n\in G$.